# How can I add validation to a form in front end HTML in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function to validate inputs on an HTML form (it's a sidebar on Google Sheets):

*Credit to Chicago Computers Classes*

```
function validate() {
    var fieldsToValidate = document.querySelectorAll("#userform input, #userform select");
    return Array.prototype.every.call(fieldsToValidate, function(el){
      return el.checkValidity();
    });
  }
```

And then I call this function with an IF statement before adding the data back to my spreadsheet.

```
 if(validate()){
      var familyName = document.getElementById("family_name");
      var semester = document.getElementById("semester");
      var rowData = {familyName: family_name.value, semesterApp: semester.value};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterRun).addNewRow(rowData);
     } else {
    //  handle this later
     }
  }
```

It's not working. The drop down menu fails to load the options and the data in the form doesn't get added when the button is clicked.

I'll appreciate any help you could provide.

This is the HTML form:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div id="userform">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="family_name">Family name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="family_name" required>
   </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="semester">Applying for semester</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="semester" required>
        <option></option>
      </select>
     </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton">Run</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the front end scripts:

```
      function afterButtonClicked(){
  
    if(validate()){
      var familyName = document.getElementById("family_name");
      var semester = document.getElementById("semester");
      var rowData = {familyName: family_name.value, semesterApp: semester.value};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterRun).addNewRow(rowData);
     } else {
      handle this later
     }
  }
  
  function afterRun(e) {
    var familyName = document.getElementById("family_name");
    familyName.value = "";
  }
  
  
  function validate() {
    var fieldsToValidate = document.querySelectorAll("#userform input, #userform select");
    return Array.prototype.every.call(fieldsToValidate, function(el){
      return el.checkValidity();
    });
  }
  
  
  function afterSidebarLoads() {
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDropDownArrayReturned).getDropDownArray();
        
  }
  
  function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays) {
    var semester = document.getElementById("semester");
  
    arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent = r[0];
      semester.appendChild(option);
    });
  }
  
  document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click", afterButtonClicked);
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterSidebarLoads);
```

These are the two functions running in the back end:

```
    function addNewRow(rowData) {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("dataFromInput");
  sheet1.appendRow([rowData.familyName, rowData.semesterApp]);
  
  return true;
    
}

function getDropDownArray() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("dropDownMenuSem");
  return sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues(); // [[AUG - DEC 2020], [FEB - JUN 2021], [AUG - DEC 2021], [FEB - JUN 2022], [AUG - DEC 2022], [FEB - JUN 2023]]
  
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and `It's not working. The drop down menu fails to load the options and the data in the form doesn't get added when the button is clicked.`. In your situation, `validate()` is always `false`?

Comment: Please share the HTML form in order to understand the above mentioned relationship. Plus, I believe that if the data in the `select` input field doesn't get populated the `validate()` function cannot work properly. So the problem might be found in the drop-down creation.

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment. I believe the problem is then in your Server side environment. Please show how you are returning the `options` elements to the `SuccessHandler`

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you for your answer! I just added the two functions running in the back end. Could it be the `Array.prototype.every.call()` method that is not supported in GAS?

Comment: It's supported. See view> executions> clear run as me filter on top left

Answer (score 0):

I've been following the *Chicago Computers Classes* video series too and had the same problem.

Unfortunately I can't explain why the function validate() won't work, but I've been able to make it work by using **.forEach()** instead of **Array.prototype.every.call()**.

This is the code after the chance:

```
function validate() {
  var fieldsToValidate = document.querySelectorAll("#userform input");
  var isValid = true;
  fieldsToValidate.forEach(f => {
    if (f.checkValidity() === false) {
      isValid = false;
    }
  })
  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Other possibility is the lack of the "//" befor "handle this later" on the first html you provided.